# Access external URL with Ajax. Works in PC, but not in mobile

Tags: ajax, phonegap-build

I'm creating a test project to learn about the phonegap build.
I make a simple index.html with a jquery code, to access a external URL and return me success or error.
The project works in my PC, returning sucess. But after compile in Phonegap Build and install in Android, the ajax returns error. 
I already looked for tips in google, but nothind worked for me. 
Here is my html file:
http://pastebin.com/R0SvDf03
And here is my config.xml file: http://pastebin.com/KsVc8Dsh
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using http://build.phonegap.com/, start over. Your code is wrong. [Read Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29). Examples available in the documentation.

Comment: if they do not work, I have tutorials. Links to good videos and more.

Comment: I'd like only a simple example of an application that access a external URL using ajax.  Can you give me a tip about where do find it?

Comment: Yes, but you need to write the app correctly first, or your APP will fail. Also, if you make such and App, your may be rejected by Google and Apple.  This is mistake #5 *When designing the app, thinks phonegap works like a website or webbrowser** READ #5 of[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005).  If you know your app may be rejected, then you need to fix your original question - so I can answer your question. Your question does not ask for external URL.

Comment: I will see the link and I will try to find the error...

Answer (score 1):

In the `index.html` file change following line

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```